# Serialize a class having an interface type member using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm unable to serialize my class using protobuf-net, the issue seems to be that protobuf-net is unable to serialize the interface.

```
interface MyInterface
{
    string name;
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(MyClass1))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(MyClass2))]
public abstract class ParentClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    List<MyInterface> elements;
}


[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass1 : ParentClass, MyInterface
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    int x;
}

[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass2 : MyInterface
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    string y;
}
```

I'm unable to serialize any object of type MyClass1, since the elements is a list of interface, which can be Mylass1 or MyClass2. I'm getting some encoding not set error.

Can anyone let me know how I can resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: (this is now supported in v2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current official versions I don't include interface serialization support. However, I do have a patch contributed (from another user) that seems to enable this.

I haven't applied this patch to the core yet, simply because I *need* to focus on finishing "v2" first before adding more features (especially as the feature would need to be completely re-implemented for v2), but I'm happy to share the patch with you if you would like.

Alternatively: use a base-class instead of an interface. That *is* supported (via `[ProtoInclude]`) - however, the fact that your `MyClass1` already has a parent class complicates matters somewhat.

---

Edit: this is now supported in v2. The code must know about the expected concrete implementations, obviously - but includes can now be attached to interfaces (or optionally  specified in code for vanilla POCO models).

Comment: It'll be great if you can share the patch....

Also i was wondering if I can plug protobuf-net with AppFabric, have you tried that yet? btw..great work on the project !

Comment: @ace email me (see profile) for the patch. Re ppfabroc, not since an early beta. But you can always just give it the blob :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you need to add:

```
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(MyClass1))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(MyClass2))]
```

to both your `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`since you inherit from `MyInterface` and the serialization wont know the type.